# Subquery: return the CustomerID and TerritoryID from the Customer table where the name on the SalesTerritory Table is 'Central'

Tags: sql

I am asked to return the CustomerID and TerritoryID from the Customer table where the name on the SalesTerritory Table is 'Central'. I am to write this as a subquery.

So how would I quite go about this? I know I will have to use a WHERE ______ = 'Central' , but how do I tie that into a subquery.

Comment: Please post the table structure (coulmns) and the query you tried yourself.

Comment: With the little information you share, doesnt seem to need a subquery. But Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't need a subquery, you need a join. Here 'name' will be the name of the column that sales territory names (in the sales territory table).  refers to the column in each table that you will join on. These will each hold the same information. Without seeing your data, it looks like you will need to join TerritoryID from the Customer table onto a corresponding TerritoryID in the SalesTerritory table. Hope this helps!

```
Select CustomerID, TerritoryID 
from Customer as c
join SalesTerritory as s on c.<column name> = s.<column name>
where name = 'Central'
```